# How can I set a different \topskip for different pages?

Tags: xetex, header-footer, plain-tex

I tried to write a letter with a different value for `\topskip` on the first page because of the the address field. This works fine:

```tex
\tracingoutput=1%
\pdfpagewidth=210mm%
\pdfpageheight=297mm%
\hsize=\pdfpagewidth \advance\hsize by -50mm%
\vsize=\pdfpageheight \advance\vsize by -50mm%
\advance\hoffset by -1in \advance\hoffset by 25mm%
\advance\voffset by -1in%
\parindent=0pt%
%
\topskip=130mm%
Page 1
\vfill\eject
\topskip=50mm%
Page 2
\bye
```

Now I tried to move the definition into `\makeheadline`, but it does not work at all.

```
\def\makeheadline{
  \ifnum\pageno=1
    \topskip=130mm
  \else
    \topskip=50mm
  \fi
  \nointerlineskip}
```

I would have understood, if it does not work on the first page. But it has no effect at all, neither on the first nor on the second page.

What is the right way to modify `\topskip`?

Comment: no need to change topskip just use `\vglue 80mm` on the first page

Comment: Never add `%` after a constant or an explicit length. The resulting space generated by the endline is ignored anyway, and in some cases it might be *necessary*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain TeX's `\makeheadline` macro is used to add the page head to the final shipped out page *after* the page breaking as been done:

```
\def\plainoutput{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
  \advancepageno
...
```

As such `\topskip` is set at the wrong time to have any effect on the spacing. `\topskip` is consulted when the first (typically line) box is added to each page, it needs to have an affect *before* page breaking so that if you have a large topskip the lines start lower down the page and less content will fit.

To arrange a larger space on the first page, simply set `\topskip` for your standard later pages and then insert

```
\vglue 80mm
```

on the first page, either explicitly or by adding this to the definition of whatever title or opening command your document has. `\vglue` is a macro wrapping the `vskip` primitive but inserting a rule so the space is not dropped at the start of the page.